# Get FileNotFoundException error when call a ActiveX in SSIS script task

Tags: sql-server-2008, com, ssis, activex

I need call a ActiveX in my SSIS package, so I use script task and write the following C# script:

```
public void Main()
{
    clsAptFdbReader objFdbReader = new clsAptFdbReader("UnitedStates20000830.fdb");
    objFdbReader.OpenFdb(false);
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Get a error:

> Error:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.APTFDBReader,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified. File name:
>   'Interop.APTFDBReader,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'    at
>   ST_320325ad8e2543f09ee688d809f58ee7.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = SHINETECHCHINA\xugy LOG:
>   DisplayName = Interop.APTFDBReader,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null  (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program
>   Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/binn/ LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly :
>   (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application
>   configuration file: C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\binn\DtsDebugHost.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file
>   from
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to
>   reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based
>   assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL file:///C:/Program
>   Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/binn/Interop.APTFDBReader.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/binn/Interop.APTFDBReader/Interop.APTFDBReader.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/binn/Interop.APTFDBReader.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/binn/Interop.APTFDBReader/Interop.APTFDBReader.EXE.
>
> --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments,
>   SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle
>   typeOwner)    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature
>   sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle
>   typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String
>   name, BindingFlags bindingFlags,
>   Binder binder, Object target, Object[]
>   providedArgs, ParameterModifier[]
>   modifiers, CultureInfo culture,
>   String[] namedParams)    at
>   System.Type.InvokeMember(String name,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object target, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: After I manually copy the Interop.APTFDBReader.DLL to C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/binn/ the problem will be fixed.

Is this the only solution to fixed this problem?
I try to install the Interop.APTFDBReader.DLL to GAC, but it need to be strong named and the Interop.APTFDBReader.DLL is generated automatically.

Comment: Similar problem with autogenerated Interop.MapPoint!Solved with your comment! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the interop as part of your build using TLBIMP.EXE, and give it arguments to build a strong name.

I'm not sure if it's wise to install that interop into the GAC, though, if it's based on a third-party COM server?